# ASP.NET Grid with paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What grid control can I use that will give me paging out of the box?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listview would be the best choice.

Gridview would be the least amount of work.

For MVC webgrid is very easy

Comment: +1 for webgrid. Comes with MVC and is easy to use. Can choose which columns to use and desired format, or generates itself from your model.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has paging in a grid out of the box,

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid

Answer (score 0):

We use [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/), which is free and supports paging, column size adjustment, JQuery Themeroller integration, inline editing and loads of other goodies.